# A subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How can I  prove that a finite dimensional subspace of Hilbert space is closed?
I assume that there is a sequence in this subspace which is convergent and I want to show that this limit is actually in the same subspace any help?

Comment: Well, since you have a finite base, everything just boils down to proving convergence in $\Bbb R^n$ and furthermore, componentwise, $\Bbb R^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $Y$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of a normed space $X$. All the norms in finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent, so if $e_i$ is a basis of $Y$ and  $y = \sum y_i e_i$ is the decomposition of $y\in Y$, there are constants $C_1>0$ and $C_2>0$ such that
$$ C_1\|y\|_X \le \max |y_i| \le C_2 \|y\|_X$$
Let a sequence $y^n \in Y$ converges to $x \in X$, the components of $y_i^n$ of $y^n$ on the basis $e_i$ satisfy for $n, m \in {\mathbb N}$
$$\max_i |y_i^n - y_i^m|\le C_2 \|y^n - y^m\|_X$$
hence they are a Cauchy sequence. Let $y_i = \lim_n y_i^n$ and $y = \sum y_i e_i$. We have
$$C_1 \|y^n - y\|_X\le \max_i |y_i^n - y_i|\mathop{\longrightarrow}_\limits{n\to \infty} 0$$
Hence $x = y\in Y$.

Comment: How about the relation between \(C1) and \(C2) because as I see here we have only the constant \(C2) ?

Comment: See the changes above. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Can you show me how y can be in Y

Comment: I don't understand the question. When I prove that $\sum_i y_i^n e_i \longrightarrow \sum y_i e_i$, it is clear that the limit belongs to $Y$ as it is a linear combination of the $e_i$.